# CoreGraphics elements inside SKNode

Tags: ios, core-graphics, sprite-kit

I'm building game-type app using SpriteKit. In one of the scenes I want to create an area, in with user will be able to draw. Sadly using SKShapeNodes produces jagged lines and causes FPS to drop. I thought about using Core Graphics method, but I need drawn lines to be a part of a Node. So is there a way to use Node as a canvas for CG?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can draw to a CGImage and create a SKTexture from that using [`textureWithCGImage:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKTexture_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKTexture/textureWithCGImage%3a)

Comment: Feels a bit hacky. I was hoping there would be more elegant solution, but I guess I will have to go with Your suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: It's perfectly legal. If you were using cocos2d you'd essentially be doing the same thing, drawing onto a CCRenderTexture and then creating a sprite from the texture (or using the texture directly, that's the main difference).

Answer (score 1):

From the [SKNode documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/Reference/Reference.html):

> Unlike views, you cannot create SKNode subclasses that perform custom drawing.

So I think the answer is **no, you can't do that.**

Each node does have a `scene` property, and the `scene` does have a link to the `view` that contains it. But the thing that makes sprite animation fast is that sprites are canned -- the images have already been drawn and just need to be copied. Node types other than `SKSpriteNode` are similarly optimized for speed. Accordingly, there are no drawing methods in the sprite classes -- no opportunity for your code to do custom drawing.

Comment: Well, thats what I feared. But It makes sense.